# kernel stack inpage error with blue screen death

Tags: boot, operating-system, bsod

I recently had the kernal stack inpage error and my system crashed. I read a few suggestions and tried a check disk. But no effect on that. Now, I even can not boot with any OS cds, the result is Nothing!

How can I rollback the configuration make it work? The only thing, I can boot Ubuntu live cd. :D

Comment: run Memtest from Ubuntu live cd

Answer (score 1):

[From Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315266) : 
This issue can occur if a requested page of kernel data could not be read from the paging file into memory, or the master boot record is infected with a virus.

Therefore can be a corrupted filesystem or hard disk, this error can be caused also by corrupted device driver, and also for a virus infection .

You could try to check disk with Scan Disk or try to restore system from a previous restore point if you are on XP,Vista or 7 .

Can you start the system in Safe Mode ?

Comment: Hi aleroot, thanks for your instant response. After encountering that problem, I decided to format entire disk. So, I have deleted the partitions. After that, no more windows. Now that not even detecting the any bootable disk except ubuntu live cd. I tried to wipe out entire  disk with Ultimate Boot CD, that cd too not getting detected. Simply its showing BOOTMGR missing. Please help to resolve this issue. If you need further info ask me. thanks

Comment: Maybe hard disk have some problem ...  Have you tried to replace hard disk with another ?